# Does a photon emitted in a potential well due to transitions undergoe a blueshift?

Tags: particle-physics

This idea is related to that of gravitational redshift. As a photon climbs away from a gravity source it loses energy. In case of the finite potential well or infinite potential well as the transition s of electrons emit photons, will the photon have more energy at the top as it has more potential at top and suffer blueshift?

Comment: Good question. Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. I made some editorial changes to your post. You will get more responses to your questions if you take the time to punctuate correctly and spell words correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you're misinterpreting the energy diagram for the finite and infinite wells?

[image]

[image]

The vertical scale is the energy, not the height.  The spatial degree of freedom is the horizontal axis.

Note that the potential is unchanging with distance except at the boundaries where the potential is discontinuous; a particle is free within the well.

Comment: So when a photon is emitted does it also has 1 dimensional freedom? How does it get out of the well or stays there?

Answer (score 0):

We normally assume the well is due to an electrostatic potential i.e. the potential energy of the electron is lowered because it interacts with some system of electrical charges.

However photons do not feel any force from an electrical charge because they are themselves not charged. So if a photon is emitted by the electron at the bottom of the potential well it will not be redshifted because it does not have to climb out of any potential well.

Comment: What about the gravitational potential due to the mass of the electron?

Comment: Is that likely to be significant?

Comment: Compared to zero it is.

Comment: Anywho, I believe there should be a (very) small redshift due to the gravitational potential acting on the energy of the photon...

Comment: @hft: The point is that we are considering an electron in a potential well, not an isolated electron. So the gravitational potential is undefined. For example, if the potential well is caused by a proton (e.g. an electron in a hydrogen atom) then the gravitational potential of the proton exceeds the electron by a factor 2000. If it's a uranium atom the factor is another 238 times greater still. It is certainly possible to calculate the red shift due to an isolated electron (guesstimating how localised the electron is), but this isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Why is everyone using 'red shift' shouldn't it be blue shift instead if it happens? As the photon will be moving upwards out of the box and will experience more potential at the top than at the bottom

Comment: Another sub-question is what I never understood is that light is a combination of electric and magnetic field.So if photon has an electric field why it does not interact with that of the external field applied?

Comment: @Air: a photon has an **oscillating** electric field so the net field integrated over time is zero and the net force integrated over time is zero. The instantaneous force is not zero, which is why a radio wave photon can make the electrons in the aerial oscillate.